# Weakly Collectionwise Normal Spaces

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

I was looking at a pdf of open problems in point set topology, and encountered a few terms I didn't know, but for most I could find a definition on the internet. However, this definition seems to evade me, I can find nothing about Weakly Collectionwise Normal spaces, only Collectionwise Normal spaces.
If anyone would mind providing me with a description/definition of this, it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This property  was defined by F.D. Tall in a paper called *weakly collectionwise Hausdorff spaces* (Top. Proc. 1, 295-304, 1976), according to his survey in Open Problems in Topology.

It means that if we have an infinite discrete family of closed subsets $F_i, i \in I$ of size some cardinal $\lambda$, then there exists a subfamily $F_i, i \in J$ of that same size $\lambda$ that can be separated by disjoint open sets (so $F_i \subseteq U_i, i \in J$ open with $U_i \cap U_{i'} = \emptyset$ for $i \neq i'$ in $J$.)

This contrasts with the usual notion in that there we must be able to separate the *whole* original subfamily $F_i, i \in I$, not "just" a same-sized subfamily of it.

A question (maybe still open) from the survey:

> Is it consistent that all normal first countable spaces are weakly collectionwise normal, but that there is one that is not collectionwise normal?

So I'd say it's a pretty obscure property (it's not in Engelking or the Encyclopedia of General Topology), maybe only introduced for the benefit of studying this question...